# Android Button java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

```
Button conn_btn;
Button send_btn;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    conn_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.conn_btn);
    send_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
    ...
}


public void changeConnectionStatus(Boolean status, Context context) {
    connected = status;     
    if(status){
        conn_btn.setText(context.getString(R.string.disconnect));
        send_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        conn_btn.setText(context.getString(R.string.connect));
        send_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I keep getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" error when calling changeConnectionStatus(...)!

Comment: what line do you get the error?

Comment: when calling changeConnectionStatus();

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace? Its hard to tell which point is giving the exception, especially since there are multiple points in that method that could cause that.

Comment: No, which precise line causes the error?  It's in the stack trace in logcat.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in Android.. How can I find that stack trace?

Comment: Being new should not excuse you from using Google first!  However, it's in the logcat view in DDMS.

Comment: Where have you declared connected variable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to update button from AsyncTask "doInBackGround()"... So, the solution is to update it from "onPostExecute()". Also i was calling changeConnectionStatus() before findViewById (thanks user2707175).

Answer (score -1):

You don't provide too much information. Please join the Logcat.

Two the most probable reasons which come to my mind:
- either in onCreate method `findViewById` doesn't find the button with give id
- either you sometimes execute `changeConnectionStatus` before `findViewById`

Comment: And of course you can use debugging to easily detect if it's one of the cases above.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer guys? If you give negative points, why don't you explain why?

Comment: Because you posted an answer which depends on nothing, your guessing is not an answer!

Comment: Because the question is very unprecise thus answer cannot be precise. However please note that in my answer I mentionned two the most probable reasons. THus I believe it can still help.

Comment: Comment with suggestions to make the question more precise